# AppEngine Jersey Junit tests not working (api not registered for this thread)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, junit4

I'm having a really hard time getting Jersey, AppEngine and JUnit to work. Current error is following:

**No API environment is registered for this thread.**

I'm doing following:

- Loading the helper.setUp() (LocalDataStoreService) over JUnit @Before annotation
- Creating an instance of the Grizzly Webserver over the JUnit @Before annotation
- Executing the testCreateCard test
- Stopping the Grizzly Webserver
- Running the helper.tearDown() method over JUnit @After annotation

I launch (Run as) Junit Test with Eclipse Indigo (I include the jars over the Java BuildPath).

It seems like Jersey or the Grizzly Webcontainer is opening new threads which doesn't work with the local datastore methods helper.setUp() and helper.tearDown().

I have found a few questions/answers but not related to using AppEngine with Jersey.

Is there anyone that can help? Is a setup with Jersey and AppEngine and JUnit actually possible? I tried several possibilities with rest-assured and jersey-test-framework but all tries ended up in errors and debugging and also a post in to the AppEngine Mailinglist without any results.

My last hope is my current setup with:

- Grizzly 2.1 (provided by Jersey)
- Jersey 1.12
- JUnit 4.10

Stacktrace is following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
    at  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:86)
at     com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:96)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.<init>(Key.java:106)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.<init>(Key.java:90)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.<init>(Key.java:86)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:125)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:106)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.<init>(DatastoreFieldManager.java:189)
at  org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertPreProcess(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:354)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:267)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:256)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3185)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.makePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3161)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1298)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1175)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:669)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:694)
at com.acolsolutions.loyaltycard.dataobjects.CardDAO.create(CardDAO.java:23)
at com.acolsolutions.loyaltycard.resources.CardResource.create(CardResource.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:215)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:185)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:163)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.service(HttpHandlerChain.java:207)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:163)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:164)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:816)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:566)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:546)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Jersey Test class looks following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;

import com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

public class CardResourceTests {
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
        new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()); 

private HttpServer httpServer;
private URI uri;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    helper.setUp();

    uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.acolsolutions.loyaltycard.resources");
    httpServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, rc);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    helper.tearDown();

    httpServer.stop();
}

@Test
public void testCreate() {
    boolean thrown = false;
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);
    JSONObject card = new JSONObject();

    try {
        card.put("id", "1")
        .put("name", "Name of Card")
        .put("code", "123456")
        .put("codeTypeId", "1")
        .put("cardProviderName", "The Card Provider")
        .put("picturePath", "provider.jpg")
        .put("cardProviderUrl", "http://www.provider.com")
        .put("creationDate", "Sun Jun 10 08:55:14 UTC 2012")
        .put("modificationDate","Sun Jun 10 08:55:14 UTC 2012");
    webResource.path("cards").type("application/json").post(card);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        thrown = true;          
    }

    assertEquals("Result", false, thrown);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to use grizzly if you're using appengine? Appengine is your container, not grizzly..

Comment: Thanks for bringing me on to this path Rick. Yes it would be great to use AppEngine as container. But how can I start the whole web framework over the JUnit Before and After annotations? When I run JUnit I would like that my environment is starting up for the test and then shutting down again. The Google documentation only mentions starting it over the command line. I just read that also Jetty will spawn new processes. How can I limit the webserver to only spawn one process?

Comment: You don't start the web container for a unit test. That's what the appengine test harness is for. You should test your jersey services programmatically, not by sending them requests. In other words, don't use the jersey client classes to send a request but rather just call the methods directly on the service classes. If you start up a container, that's not a unit test... that's an integration test.

Comment: Ok I get it. I'll try to do that, thanks. But even then there seem many people out there that use JUnit for Integration Tests then. So I guess they are "abusing" JUnit in this case? How would I do an integration test then? Just by writing a client and connect to the server after it has been started?

Comment: No abusing, it's a tool for doing whatever you want. But in this case it's just wrong because you're starting up the appengine mock-datastore and a non-appengine container and that's just not going to work. Yes, to do integration testing with appengine the best thing to do is start the development server from the command line and then write scripts to hit it.